# Importing pdf in R through package "tm"

Tags: r, pdf, tm

I know the practical example to get pdf in "R" workspace through package "tm" but not able to understand how the code is working and thus not able to import the desired pdf. The pdf imported in the following code is "tm" vignette.

The code is

```
if(file.exists(Sys.which("pdftotext"))) {
    pdf <- readPDF(PdftotextOptions = "-layout")(elem = list(uri = vignette("tm")$pdf),
                                                 language = "en",
                                                 id = "id1")
    pdf[1:13]
}
```

The "tm" is vignette. While the pdf which I am trying to bring is "different". So how to change the above code to bring my pdf in the workspace. **minn** is the pdf document which I am trying to import.

like

```
if(file.exists(Sys.which("pdftotext"))) {
        pdf <- readPDF(PdftotextOptions = "-layout")(elem = list(uri = vignette("minn")$pdf),
                                                     language = "en",
                                                     id = "id1")
        pdf[1:13]
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Without a question this is in jeopardy of being closed fairly quickly...

Comment: I am trying to import pdf throught the above code but after certain attempts unable to do so. The name of pdf which is kind of very large is 100 pages. So how to replace the "tm" name in the above code with the pdf I wanted to bring in R.

Comment: `vignette("tm")$pdf` is a pointer to a vignette in the `tm` package. `uri` should be a filename or path....probably something like `"minn.pdf"`.

Comment: @Thomas seems to be near but it gave me error . Error in PDF_Date_to_POSIXt(dt) : invalid multibyte string 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that problem is with the PDF which I was trying to read. However the code goes like the below. Thanks Thomas for the lead. The link for pdf is "http://www.wine-economics.org/workingpapers/AAWE_WP16.pdf"

```
tt <- readPDF(PdftotextOptions="-layout")
rr <- tt(elem=list(uri="AAWE_WP16.pdf"),language="en",id="id1")
rr[1:15]
```