# Reading Web Data In R and getting strange symbols

Tags: r

https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/61064765E6620C413FE3010AC51BDFA9098F

I would like to read the above data into a data frame in R. I have tried using
`readLines()`
as well as `download.file()` (with the "curl" method), but I am reading in some strange symbols instead.

Does anyone have any tips on how to read this in?

Comment: It's because you are reading a .pdf. PDFs are containers, not formats, so whether this file is readable will depend on what was contained in the original document it was encoded from and how it was encoded. Try here for reading a PDF into R: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17415239/importing-pdf-in-r-through-package-tm

Comment: As an alternative you might want to try [tabula](http://tabula.technology/) or [pdftables](https://pdftables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is readable, which in this case it is, then I've found that the easiest way to extract it is often to just manually select the entirety of the text you're interested in, paste it into a text editor, fix any little issues that were introduced by the select-copy-paste, and then save it as a plain text or CSV or tab-delimited file. [`Vim`](http://www.vim.org/download.php) can be an incredibly useful tool for this purpose.

I copied the entire content of the table into a vim buffer and then had to make 32 changes to fix little issues. The issues were as follows:

1. there were extra blank lines where page breaks occurred; I ran `:g/^$/d` to eliminate those.
2. some cells in the table had line breaks embedded in them; I normalized those to spaces by joining the lines. Since there are normally supposed to be three separators per row (because there are four cells per row) I searched for `^\([^\t]*\t\)\{0,2}[^\t]*$` to find lines that had fewer than three separators.

Then I was able to read in the data as follows:

```
df <- read.table('data.tsv',sep='\t',header=T,quote=NULL);
head(df,50);
##               Retail.Branding     Marketing.Name         Device                     Model
## 1                                                        AD681H Smartfren Andromax AD681H
## 2                                                         FJL21                     FJL21
## 3                                                          Luno                      Luno
## 4                                                           T31             Panasonic T31
## 5                                                      hws7721g        MediaPad 7 Youth 2
## 6                          3Q            OC1020A        OC1020A                   OC1020A
## 7                     7Eleven              IN265          IN265                     IN265
## 8  A.O.I. ELECTRONICS FACTORY             A.O.I.     TR10CS1_11                   TR10CS1
## 9                   AG Mobile   AG_Go-Tab_Access      md789hwag          AG Go-Tab Access
## 10                  AG Mobile         AG_Tab_7_0     AG_Tab_7_0                AG_Tab_7_0
## 11                  AG Mobile              Ghost          Ghost                     Ghost
## 12                  AG Mobile             Status         Status                    Status
## 13                  AG Mobile              Swift          Swift                     Swift
## 14                  AG Mobile              ULTRA          Ultra                     Ultra
## 15                       AMTC AMTC MD1001 Tablet         MD1001                    MD1001
## 16                       AMTC        AMTC MD7008        MD7008A                    MD7008
## 17                       AMTC        AMTC MD7081        MD7081A                    MD7081
## 18                        AOC          A2272PWHT         AOC_WW                    G2SMNT
## 19                        AOC      AOC-A2272PW4T         AOC_WW                 G3SMNTA22
## 20                        AOC      AOC-A2272PW4T         AOC_WW                 G3SMNTA24
## 21                        AOC      AOC-A2472PW4T      G3SMNTA24                 G3SMNTA24
## 22                         AV               AV10     RCT6203W46                      AV10
## 23                         AV                AV7     RCT6773W22                       AV7
## 24                      AZBox            AZDroid        AZDroid                   AZDroid
## 25                      AZPEN         AZPEN A720      wing-inet                      A720
## 26                      AZPEN         AZPEN A920       wing-ibt                      A920
## 27                     Abocom       AboCom A08SM            A08                      A08S
## 28                       Acer                                C6                 Acer E320
## 29                       Acer                                C6          Acer E320-orange
## 30                       Acer                                C7                      E330
## 31                       Acer                               C8n                      E350
## 32                       Acer                                K3                      E130
## 33                       Acer                                T2                     AT390
## 34                       Acer                             T603T                     TD600
## 35                       Acer                                a3                    Stream
## 36                       Acer                                a5                      S300
## 37                       Acer                                c4                      E310
## 38                       Acer                                k4                      E140
## 39                       Acer                                k5                      E210
## 40                       Acer             A1-713   acer_aprilia                    A1-713
## 41                       Acer             A1-810          mango                    A1-810
## 42                       Acer             A1-811          mango                    A1-811
## 43                       Acer             A1-830         ducati                    A1-830
## 44                       Acer               A100        vangogh                      A100
## 45                       Acer               A101        vangogh                      A101
## 46                       Acer               A110           a110                      A110
## 47                       Acer             A3-A10           zara                    A3-A10
## 48                       Acer             A3-A11           zara                    A3-A11
## 49                       Acer             A3-A20    acer_harley                    A3-A20
## 50                       Acer          A3-A20FHD acer_harleyfhd                 A3-A20FHD
```

I've published the fixed-up tab-separated file at http://pastebin.com/RqWtwvej, so now you can just run

```
df <- read.table('http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=RqWtwvej',sep='\t',header=T,quote=NULL);
```

to get it.